# Recycleview with pagination

Tags: php, android, retrofit

I'm working with `Retrofit API` and my web services contain backend pagination.Response data will load into `Recyceview.initial` view i'm requested 10 records to my `Recyclerview` (limit=10,offset=0).when user scroll down the recycle list, I want to request next 10 records from the backend.scroll up, previous data should be there.

I have tried the code.
but when I scroll my list down, all request are done at once and finally showing an empty list.

this is my code

```
int limit=10,offset=0; //set globally
boolean isLastPage=false;



public void filterFunc(){
        OrderArr.clear();

        WebserviceAPI apiService =retrofit.create(WebserviceAPI.class);
        Call<AllOrdersResponse> call = apiService.filter("list",token_acces, limit, offset);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<AllOrdersResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AllOrdersResponse> call, Response<AllOrdersResponse> response) {

                try {

                    AllOrdersResponse result = response.body();
                    List<AllOrders> data=result.getData();
                    status=result.isStatus();
                    msg= result.getMessage();
                    count=result.getCount(); // total record count without pagination

                    if(status){
                        for (AllOrders a: data){
                            if (count >= offset) {
                                OrderArr.add(new AllOrders(a.getId_order(),a.getReference(), a.getAddress1(),"LKR "+a.getTotal_products(),a.getStatus()));
                            } else {
                                isLastPage = true;
                            }
                        }
                        progress.dismiss();
                        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        RecycleOrderList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        adapter = new HistoryAdapter(OrderArr);
                        RecycleOrderList.setAdapter(adapter);// set adapter on recyclerview
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Notify the adapter
                    }else{
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }

                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                    progress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No orders to display",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AllOrdersResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("fragres",""+t.getMessage());

            }
        });

        scrollRecycle(type);

    }



public void scrollRecycle(){
        RecycleOrderList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                int firstVisibleItemPosition= layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                int last= layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                try {

                    if (!isLastPage){
                        if ( ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0)) {
                            progress.show();

                            if(last==visibleItemCount-1){
                                offset=offset+limit;
                                filterFunc();
                            }
                        }
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }

                }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){

                }
                Log.d("scroll "," limit "+limit+" offset"+offset+" loading page "+isLastPage);
```

Comment: use google's [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) library

Comment: Do you have any sample?

Comment: its on the page i linked above